# Amplitude Estimating Using a Windowed DFT

Tags: dft, estimation, window-functions, frequency-domain

Let's say we want to estimate the amplitude A of a mono-frequent signal using a windowed DFT. The frequency of the signal is unknown, and the frequency resolution of the DFT is limited, thus it cannot be expected that there is a DFT bin that matches this frequency directly. Therefore, A is estimated from the amplitude of the next closest DFT bin. Now the question is,

should the frequency response of the window exhibit a narrow or a wide mainlobe to obtain a good estimate, and why?

Comment: Look up “Flat Top window”.

Comment: So the answer is it should have a narrow mainlobe? Hence the desire to have the spectrum of the window look like an impulse?

Answer (score 4):

I have several blog articles that solve this problem *exactly* in a theoretical sense, and quite accurately in an implementattion.

### 3. DFT Pure Tone Frequency Formulas

- [Exact Frequency Formula for a Pure Real Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/773.php)
- [Two Bin Exact Frequency Formulas for a Pure Real Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1095.php)
- [Improved Three Bin Exact Frequency Formula for a Pure Real Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1108.php)
- [A Two Bin Exact Frequency Formula for a Pure Complex Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1039.php)
- [Three Bin Exact Frequency Formulas for a Pure Complex Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1043.php)

### 4. DFT Phase and Amplitude

- [Phase and Amplitude Calculation for a Pure Real Tone in a DFT: Method 1](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/787.php)
- [Phase and Amplitude Calculation for a Pure Complex Tone in a DFT](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1127.php)
- [Phase and Amplitude Calculation for a Pure Complex Tone in a DFT using Multiple Bins](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1143.php)

The rest of the articles are pretty good too. ;-)

I posted one this morning:

- [Angle Addition Formulas from Euler's Formula](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1238.php)